# SXA Mega Menu with Navigation Component

Tags: sxa, components

Has anyone created a `mega menu` using the `SXA Navigation component`? Something similar to Home Depot and many others. The functionality includes a top level that can be clicked, but also on hover shows all of the children and sub-children of that item.

I was surprised this variant wasn't built into the component, so I figured I'd ask before re-creating my own implementation.

Thanks!

Comment: did you check this article that Sitecore provided? https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/the-navigation-renderings.html

Comment: Yeah, not much there. Just a few bullets on out of the box options.

Comment: No - I've always created a custom navigation component for Mega Menu, the OOTB component does not lend itself to be easily customized to that.

Comment: @RichardSeal did you base it off of an existing component or just go completely custom?

Comment: I've seen it done by adding a separate SXA navigation for each mega menu item, and a few other components for the header, then a lot of custom styling / js to make it look right. But it is hard to maintain. I'd recommend to start from scratch and draw inspiration from the Navigation component.